# Frontend API call receiving 403 error status

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http

I'm trying to make Oxford Dictionary API call using axios, but it is having cors issue. I also added proxy but that returns 403 error status. I also used it anywhere. Heroku and that didn't work either. So is there a way to make this API without any issue? Below is the code of the API call.

```
axios.get("https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-gb/ace?strictMatch=false", {
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "app_id": my_app_id,
      "app_key": my_app_key,
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the API key? It seems like using the dictionary API is not free of charge. HTTP code 403 tells that the requested resource is forbidden, so your program does not have access.

Comment: Yes I have a valid app id and app key provided to me after registering. The headers also have the same

Comment: afaik `application/json` should be `content-type` not `accept`

Comment: even with that its not working, getting `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a backend to make this API call to you and not make this API call directly in the frontend (React). Furthermore, this will hide your sensitive information (API key and app id) and also will remove the CORS errors.

Node.JS Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bassi-xff43?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I've created a simple Node server to you can try it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bassi-xff43?file=/src/index.js